# Don't restart docker container on host reboot. Restart the container only when it crashed due to error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers, docker-machine

I want to restart the docker container only when container crashed due to error. And don't want to restart the container if host reboots.
Which restart_policy will work for the above case?

Comment: Also see the list of [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy) in the Docker documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[**Start containers automatically**](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)

`on-failure[:max-retries]`

Restart the container if it exits due to an error, which manifests as a non-zero exit code. Optionally, limit the number of times the Docker daemon attempts to restart the container using the `:max-retries` option.

```
docker run -d --restart  on-failure[:max-retries] CONTAINER
```

**UPDATE**

A Docker host is a physical computer system or virtual machine running Linux. This can be your laptop, server or virtual machine in your data center, or computing resource provided by a cloud provider. The component on the host that does the work of building and running containers is the Docker Daemon.

[**Keep containers alive during daemon downtime**](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/live-restore/)

By default, when the Docker daemon terminates, it shuts down running containers. You can configure the daemon so that containers remain running if the daemon becomes unavailable. This functionality is called live restore. The live restore option helps reduce container downtime due to daemon crashes, planned outages, or upgrades.

### Enable live restore

There are two ways to enable the live restore setting to keep containers alive when the daemon becomes unavailable. Only do one of the following.

1. Add the configuration to the daemon configuration file. On Linux, this defaults to  `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. On Docker Desktop for Mac or Docker Desktop for Windows, select the Docker icon from the task bar, then click Preferences -> Daemon -> Advanced.

Use the following JSON to enable live-restore.

```
    {
      "live-restore": true
    }
```

Restart the Docker daemon. On Linux, you can avoid a restart (and avoid any downtime for your containers) by reloading the Docker daemon. If you use systemd, then use the command systemctl reload docker. Otherwise, send a SIGHUP signal to the dockerd process.

2. If you prefer, you can start the dockerd process manually with the `--live-restore` flag. This approach is not recommended because it does not set up the environment that systemd or another process manager would use when starting the Docker process. This can cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Will this restart the container if docker host reboots??

Comment: Is it possible ->  1. to stop all container in host reboot. Don't start it back after reboot. 2. And Restart  the container only upon container crashed with some error.